# Triangular Input Balanced

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

Let $A$ ( $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ matrix ) be lower triangular and satisfy
$AA^* = I -  bb^*$
where $b$ is a $\mathbb{C}^n$ matrix

Such $A$ is called a (lower) triangular input balanced. Show that for a given
$b$, there is always a solution $A$ of this equation with non-negative diagonal elements ($A_{kk} \geq 0$ ).

Give an expression for the
elements of this solution $A$ in terms of the elements of $b$.

Also I noticed , taking $b$ =  [1 2]<sup>T</sup> , there are no solutions for the equation

Can someone please help with the solution?

Comment: Hello and welcome to MSE! Please also provide your thoughts and comments about the question so that you may get precise answers and avoid any downvotes. Also, please format the math properly.

Comment: As you've noted in a special case, since $A$ is lower triangular, $$[AA^*]_{11} = a_{11}\overline {a_{11}} = |a_{11}|^2 \ge 0.$$ For any $b$ with $|b_1| > 1$, $$[I - bb^*]_{11} = 1 - |b_1|^2 < 0.$$ Therefore as stated, this claim is false. There need not be a solution at all, much less one with a non-negative diagonal.